# How do I get my demographics data to show up in Google Data Studio reports?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, wordpress-theming, google-tag-manager, looker-studio

I have not been able to get my demographics (sessions by age & gender) to show up in my data studio reports or in google analytics itself. I followed the recommended practice from Google to Enable Demographics and Interests reports: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948?hl=en
but it still doenst work. I even set up google tag manager and added that bit of code to my site but still no luck.

I am also using the Wordpress BeTheme from Muffin Group and loading the tags in the SEO > General panel.

Is there a step I may have missed?

Paste this code as high in the  of the page as possible:

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Additionally, paste this code immediately after the opening  tag:

```
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Comment: Can you see these data in Google Analytics or not?

Comment: I can not see the data for Demographics, all my other data shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wait a few days or longer, particularly if your site has a low volume of sessions per day.

Google will not show you the data below a certain threshold: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en

Comment: I have some other websites that get much more traffic. I will set up Google tags in those and see if it works. If it does I will have my answer. Thanks!